# Como distinguir distintos tipos de usuario en django-restframework

Tags: python, django, api, djangorestframework, autenticación

quisiera saber si alguien me puede instruir de como seria la mejor manera para separar distintos tipos de usuarios para que estos no puedan modificar la información de ciertos endpoints sino que solo puedan leer. 
explico, quiero tener 2 tipos de usuarios:

1) Secretario Académico = el cual tiene todos los privilegios

2) Jefe de departamento = el cual puede solamente puede cambiar en ciertos 
 y leer de todos los endpoints.

De momento mi autenticacion y autorizacion la hago con los usuarios creados desde el django-Admin y lo hago de la siguiente manera.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView

from apps.facultades.models import Facultad
from .serializers import FacultadSerializer
from rest_framework_jwt.authentication import JSONWebTokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
class FacultadListView(APIView):

    authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    def get(self, request, pk):
        try:
            facultades = Facultad.objects.get(facultad_id=pk)
            serializer = FacultadSerializer(facultades)
            return Response({"facultad": serializer.data})
        except:
            return Response({"Detail": "not found"})

    def put(self, request, pk):
        saved_facultad = get_object_or_404(
            Facultad.objects.all(), facultad_id=pk)
        facultad = request.data.get('facultad')
        serializer = FacultadSerializer(
            instance=saved_facultad, data=facultad, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            facultad_saved = serializer.save()
        return Response({"success": "Facultad '{}' updated successfully".format(facultad_saved.facultad_nombre)})

    def delete(self, request, pk):
        facultad = get_object_or_404(Facultad.objects.all(), facultad_id=pk)
        facultad.delete()
        return Response({"message": "Facultad with id `{}` has been deleted.".format(pk)})


class Facultadone(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    def get(self, request):
        try:
            facultades = Facultad.objects.all()
            serializer = FacultadSerializer(facultades, many=True)
            return Response({"facultad": serializer.data})
        except:
            return Response({"Detail": "not found"})

    def post(self, request):
        facultad = request.data.get('facultad')
        serializer = FacultadSerializer(data=facultad)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            facultad_saved = serializer.save()
        return Response({"success": "Facultad: '{}' creada satisfactoriamente".format(facultad_saved.facultad_nombre)})
```

El problema con lo anterior es que solo valido si el usuario es valido pero no valido si tiene los permisos para poder cambiar los datos.
de antemano muchas gracias por cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Podrías usar el sistema de permisos includos en la librería estándar de Django `django.contrib.auth` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#handling-object-permissions y utilizar las integración que posee Django-rest-framework con este framwork como se describe aquí https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#djangomodelpermissions

Comment: @Vichoko gracias por contestar amigo y también gracias por los enlaces los veré en seguida. espero poder encontrar una solución a mi problema

Comment: De nada y te recomiendo colocar el tag python a tu pregunta para llegar a mas gente, al fin y al cabo es el lenguaje.